# How to identify webelement with dynamic id and name?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, qwebelement

I can't define webelement as it has dynamic id and name. There are iframe in another iframe. Attributes id and name for second iframe are dynamic. I need to define the second iframe to switch on it
http://prntscr.com/pqshpr
Please help me with defining this dynamic elements.

```
 WebElement chartFrameFirst = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(.//iframe)[1]"));
    driver.switchTo().frame(chartFrameFirst);
    click(By.xpath(".//div[@id=\"tv_chart_container\"]"));
    WebElement chartFrameSecond = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//iframe[@id=\"tradingview_1d329\"]"));
    driver.switchTo().frame(chartFrameSecond);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `contains()` which is a method used in XPath expression as shown below

```
WebElement chartFrameSecond = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//iframe[contains(@id,\"tradingview_\")]"));
```

Answer (score 0):

We can user index to switch frame which is inside an iframe

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0).switchTo().frame(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find number of frames and then switch to

```
int noofframes=driver.findelements(By.tagName(“iframe”)).size();
driver.switchTo().frame(1);
```

Switch to frame using frame id:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt((By.tagName(“iframe”)));
```

`driver.switchTo().frame(1);`

Hope this help